# Increase disk space on Hadoop worker nodes

Tags: hadoop, diskspace

I have a HADOOP cluster setup and i'm starting to run out of disk space.  I have an iSCSI LUN presented to all my servers and it is formatted with ext4 running LVM.  I want to know if if I need to present a new iSCSI LUN and add it to ext4 if HDFS will see the new space or is there something else I have to do?  Could I just increase the LUN from the storage side?

Answer (score 0):

In the cluster, if any of the node reaches the limit, we can recover the disk space issue by copying some of the files to the other nodes.

If there is no space on the entire cluster, then new LUN should be added.